# i18next::backendConnector: loading namespace translation for language

Tags: internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

Hello i'm using i18next for translations but also receiving following error:

```
i18next::backendConnector: loading namespace translation for language ja failed TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /locales/ja/translation.json
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11) {
  [cause]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
```

I do have my file at this path `/public/locales/ja/translation.json`

[image: translations path]

and this is how my config looks like:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

if (!i18n.isInitialized) {
  i18n
    .use(Backend)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
      supportedLngs: ['en', 'ja'],
      fallbackLng: 'ja',
      debug: true,
    });
}

export default i18n;
```

There is no failing request in network tab, json file is valid, so i feel like is some kind of missconfiguration or so. If you have any suggestions i will appreciate them a'lot! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running this lib using Node.js (at the backend).
Therefore, you get an error, since server side code doesn't understand a browser absolute path. it can only fetch using full url (which contains http & the domain).

so, you can solve this error, by specifying a full url to the json file.

If the translation file is located locally on the server, it is better to read it from disk using [i18next-fs-backend](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-fs-backend).